# Values from table1 into drop-down menu and then into new mySql table

Tags: php, mysql

I am new in PHP and I am a bit stuck with my task.

I have to get values from Table1 into the drop-down menu and then into Table2.

For now, I get the values into drop-down menu and can select them from there, but
when I add values into Table 2, I get only ID numbers of Table1.
I see those in phpMyadmin and also if I echo them.

Table1 name: people. Columns: ID, firstname, surname
Table2 name: questions. Columns: ID, firstname(from Table1 ),surname(from Table1, question.

My code so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
</head>

<?php  

include("yhendus.php");
mysql_query( "SET NAMES utf8" );
$humans = "SELECT * FROM people";
$result = mysql_query($humans) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $human_id .= "<option value='{$row['id']}'.{$row['firstname']}' . '{$row['surname']}'>{$row['firstname']} {$row['surname']}</option>";
} 

if ($_REQUEST[Send]=="Send")
{

include("yhendus1.php"); // there are 2 connection files, but is works fine

$abi7="insert into questions (id,firstname,surname,question) values 
('$_POST[id]','$_POST[user]','$_POST[user]','$_POST[question]')";

mysql_query($abi7);
}
 ?>
<body>

<form method="POST" action="kysimused.php">

Pick name:<select name="user"><? echo $human_id; ?></select> <br/><br/>
Question:<br/><br/><input type="text" name="question"> <br/><br/>

<br><br/>
<input type="submit" name="Send" value="Send">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope someone can help!

Thank You in advance!

Comment: is the $_POST values are fetched correctly?

Comment: I hope so! If I have name "Ann" in Table1 with ID "1", then if I am select that "Ann" from the drop-down menu and click Send Button, I get value 1 in Table2 column surname.

Answer (score 0):

First check out whether you are getting the proper values in POST and then try to print the sql query and run that query in phpmyadmin..you will come to know where actually the error is.

Also if the datatype of user and question in mysql is varchar then you need to pass the value as a string i.e in double qoutes in mysql query.

Thanks

Comment: I get values, but those are ID numbers of Table1 corresponding name.